# Does this matrix multiplication-like operation have a name?

Tags: matrices

The operation is similar to a matrix product, but instead of it being a sum of factors, it is a product of powers.

Say we have matrices $A = (a_{ij})$ of size $n\times m$ and $B = (b_{ij})$ of size $m\times o$, the operation aforementioned is defined by:
$$
(c_{ij}) = A\circ B\enspace \text{where}\enspace \forall i \in 1..n,j \in 1..o: c_{ij} = \prod_{k=1}^m a_{ik}^{b_{kj}}
$$

Is this operation common? Does it even have a name?

I came across this idea when reading [this article](https://www.bernh.net/media/download/papers/ldpc.pdf) on LDPC encoding and thought it would help to compute the values.